# Configure Vagrant with Xvfb Error

Tags: angularjs, selenium, vagrant, xvfb

I am configuring a vagrant machine with ubuntu 14.04, for doing some tests with selenium and protractor. I want to run all tests in that machine without having a graphic environment. So i only need a plain output by a terminal.

I am following next resources to do that :
http://linkeshkannavelu.com/2015/07/10/virtualization-using-vagrant-for-selenium-tests/comment-page-1/#comment-838
 https://www.exratione.com/2013/12/angularjs-headless-end-to-end-testing-with-protractor-and-selenium/

but when i access to vagrant machine and i try to run my tests i get next error message :

```
[1796:1796:0212/145406:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(256)] Gtk: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

[1796:1796:0212/145406:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(256)] Gtk: cannot open display:

And i am not sure what i should do...

thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

See this article: https://linuxmeerkat.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/running-a-gui-application-in-a-docker-container/

> Gtk: cannot open display

is a common error, as states on this page:

> DISPLAY has wrong value or you forgot to export it

Also doublecheck if xvfb is running in backgroud/as service.